# Getting the last word of a location string, except for special cases like "New York", "North Dakota", "South Carolina", etc

Tags: python, pandas, string, location

I'm trying to create a new field from a pandas dataframe. The field is "location" and it contains city and state information. I used a `str.split().str[-1]` function to get the last word of the location, which is usually the full state name.

The problem is states like "north carolina" become just "carolina". I would like to take special cases into account, like when `.str[-2]` = "north" or "new" or "south" or "west".

Here's an example of my code:

```
df["state"] = df.location.str.split().str[-1]
print(df.state.value_counts().reset_index())
```

And here's the output:

```
index  state  
0      california  59855  
1            york     17  
2        illinois      8  
3   massachusetts      5
```

You can see that "york" should be "new york".

I'm thinking I should write a function for the location field, like the following:

```
def get_location(x):  
   if x.str.split().str[-2] in ["new", "north", "south", "west"]:  
      return x.str.split().str[-2:]  
   else:  
      return x.str.split().str[-1]
```

The problem here is that I get the following error message when calling `get_location(df.location)`:

"The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."

Am I on the right track here? What can I do to get my new df.state field to return output like this:

```
index   state  
0       california   59855  
1         new york      17  
2         illinois       8  
3    massachusetts       5  
4   north corolina       3
```

Thank you!

Comment: What are the original locations, i.e. the values in `df['location']`?

Comment: I feel that, in this case, you should just have a list of all the states, and check that if a state is a substring of the location, then replace it with the state. This way, it's a lot less error prone than doing it programmatically.

Comment: @CodeDifferent your question got me thinking! The solution was to set the new "state" field equal to the following:
df["state"] = df.location.str.split(",").str[-1]
print(df.state.unique())

Because the "state" information is the last part of the split, and the location information is delimited by a comma, I was able to get both words by specifying that the split function should be performed with the "," delimiter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can count the length of strings using split method, something like this:

```
# Dataframe dummy from your Data:
your_df = pd.DataFrame({'location': ['New York', 'North Carolina', 'South Illinois', 'Texas', 'Florida'], 'another_field': [1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000]})

# You verify the count of strings, if there are two or more, then you return full string.
your_df['state'] = your_df['location'].apply(lambda your_location: your_location if len(your_location.split(" ")) > 1 else your_location.split(" ")[-1])
your_df
```

Output:

```
    location       another_field    state
0   New York                1000    New York
1   North Carolina          2000    North Carolina
2   South Illinois          3000    South Illinois
3   Texas                   4000    Texas
4   Florida                 5000    Florida
```

Comment: Thank you! This got me thinking. I ended up using the following function, which gave me the desired output. The thing was to split on the comma! That way, the entire state field would be split from the rest of the location information:

df["state"] = df.location.str.split(",").str[-1]
print(df.state.unique())

Comment: You're Welcome, happy coding :)